# How to show a json field from a blade view and edit multiple file uploads from json?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I'm creating a CRUD project with file uploads using json_encode for uploading the file to a database. How do I show the file that I've uploaded from the blade view? Is it possible to delete it from the view?

```
    $sid = Sid::find($id);
    $data = [];

    if($request->file('file_uploads'))
    {
        foreach($request->file('file_uploads') as $file)
        {
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $path = 'public/file/'.$sid->employee_name;
            $file->move($path, $name);
            $data[] = $name;
        }
    }

        $sid->employee_sid          = $request->employee_sid;
        $sid->employee_npk          = $request->employee_npk;
        $sid->employee_name         = $request->employee_name;
        $sid->file_uploads          = count($data)? json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($sid->file_uploads, true),$data)): $sid->file_uploads;
        $sid->save();
```

I want to show the file/image that I uploaded before in the blade view and to know if it is possible to delete it from view-blade.

This is my upload files from the edit form.

```
      <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="UploadFileSertifUnit">Upload Sertifikat Unit</label>
                                <input type="file" id="UploadFileSertifUnit" name="file_uploads[]" multiple>
                                <p>Ukuran Max : 2 MB</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to show the file above this code.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Can try use this lib.

"DropzoneJS is an open source library that provides drag’n’drop file uploads with image previews."

https://www.dropzonejs.com/